# Hiding independent variables of a function in Traditional Form

Tags: functions, output-formatting, traditional-form

I would like to perform a computation which involves fourth-order derivatives of a composite function of four variables. I am defining my function as

```
G[t_, x_, y_, z_] := (x - v*t)^2 + y^2 + z^2;
f[t_, x_, y_, z_] := f[G[t, x, y, z]];
```

So when I want to display the output of $f \partial_x f$ in traditional form, the command

```
TraditionalForm[f[t,x,y,z]*D[f[t,x,y,z],x]]
```

gives me $$2(x-tv)f((x-tv)^2 + y^2 + z^2)f'((x-tv)^2+y^2+z^2).$$

However, I would like to hide the independent variables here, and have `TraditionalForm` output an answer like $2(x-tv)ff'$ instead. I can hide the independent variables of derivatives using something like

```
TraditionalForm[...] /. Derivative[n_][x_][___] :> Derivative[n][x]
```

but I haven't been able to figure out how hide the dependent variables of the "zeroth" derivatives. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
Format[f[args___], TraditionalForm] := f;
Format[Derivative[n_][fun_][args___], TraditionalForm] := Derivative[n][fun];

f[t, x, y, z]*D[f[t, x, y, z], x]
(* 2 (-t v + x) f[(-t v + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2] Derivative[1][f][(-t v + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2] *)

f[t, x, y, z]*D[f[t, x, y, z], x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hacky, but

```
G[t_, x_, y_, z_] := (x - v*t)^2 + y^2 + z^2;
f[t_, x_, y_, z_] := f[G[t, x, y, z]];
expr = f[t, x, y, z]*D[f[t, x, y, z], x];

TraditionalForm@ToExpression[
   ToBoxes[expr, TraditionalForm] /. {RowBox[{"f", __}] :> "f", RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["f", "\[Prime]", _], __}] :> SuperscriptBox["f", "\[Prime]"]}
  ]
```

[image]